# lupdate and conditional includes in a .pro file

Tags: qt, translation

I have a .pro file that contains conditional includes, like this:

```
contains(CONFIG, embedded) {  
    SOURCES += a.cpp  
    HEADERS += a.h  
}  
else {  
    SOURCES += b.cpp  
    HEADERS += b.h  
}
```

When I run lupdate tool (lupdate myproject.pro) from a terminal, only b.h and .cpp are processed (because embedded is not in the CONFIG variable).
How can I let lupdate process ALL files contained in the .pro file?

Comment: Works for me on Qt 4.7.1 - lupdate picks strings to translate from both conditional blocks. Which version of of Qt are you building on? Are your .pro file `LANGUAGES` and `TRANSLATIONS` ok?

Comment: I found out that this works indeed.  The problem seems to be that a .cpp includes another .cpp file (!), and for one or the other reason lupdate doesn't like that (I work on OSX).

Comment: Yeah, lupdate doesn't run the files through C/C++ preprocessor. It just picks up strings to be translated from SOURCES.

Comment: But the file itself is included in the sources.      SOURCES += a.cpp b.cpp  The file a.cpp is including b.cpp and for one or the other reason the translation strings in b.cpp are not picked up.  When I remove a.cpp from the SOURCES then the strings are picked up. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a last resort, you could use the `lupdate` mode that doesn't care about the `pro` file but instead just scans files:

```
lupdate [options] [source-file|path]... -ts ts-files
```

Comment: I finally ended up by calling lupdate from a shell script (this seems to avoid the include problem). Thanks.