# Conditional commands in Qt .pro file

Tags: qt, makefile

I have doubts about my Qt .pro file... I had seen another post about a similar question [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140895/lupdate-and-conditional-includes-in-a-pro-file), but i used the contains() function and didn't work.

In the my case, i have a file called mainconfig.h where i define some project configurations flags, i really create defines there, like: "#define MY_CONFIG_DEFINE". Those flags define what menu options will be shown etc. My problem is: all files are always compiled, even when i don't use its because i defined some flag in "mainconfig.h" file. I would like to avoid compile some files than i will not use, defining some variables in my .pro file and doing conditional commands, including only the files than i want to.

Can someone help me?

I tried this in my .pro file:

```
    # This variable defines the current project ADRIANO_PROJECT = PROJECT_TYPE_1
    ADRIANO_PROJECT = PROJECT_TYPE_1

    (...) 

    FORMS += ui/form1.ui \ 
    contains(ADRIANO_PROJECT, PROJECT_TYPE_1) {
            ui/myform1.ui \
            ui/myform2.ui \ 
    }
             ui/form2.ui \
             ui/form3.ui

    (...)

    # This is only a example, ok?
```

Sorry my english and thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO your syntax is wrong. Try this instead:

```
ADRIANO_PROJECT = PROJECT_TYPE_1

FORMS += ui/form1.ui \ 
         ui/form2.ui \
         ui/form3.ui

contains(ADRIANO_PROJECT, PROJECT_TYPE_1) {
        FORMS + = ui/myform1.ui \
                  ui/myform2.ui 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sgibb, i tried this and worked... Well, at least my project compiled, but my binary has the same size before that.